# Connect to another PC on Local Network on another domain

Tags: networking, domain

I am on a local network that consists of 2 domains: domain1 and domain2.

Now I want to connect to an ip address: 192.168.40.40 that belongs to domain2, and I am currently on domain1.

So when I do the following form MY PC on domain1:

```
\\192.168.40.40\c$
```

I cannot connect since windows try to connect to that IP/PC on **domain1**, and not **domain2**

So how do I connect to that PC on domain2? It has to be something like this??

```
\\domain2\192.168.40.40\c$
```

Thank you

Comment: So when you are connecting to `\\192.169.40.40\ ` it's routing you to `\\192.168.40.40\ ` ?

Comment: no, because it is trying to access it on my current domain, which is domain1. This ip is on domain2, so I want to connect to it like that...If it was on the same domain as my PC, which is domain1, then it would have been simple - \\192.168.40.40 only

Comment: Is this a windows domain you're referring to? also how are you routing the connection from the 192.168.x.x network to the 192.169.x.x network?

Comment: yes, it is a windows domain.Sorry, made a mistake, both IPs are on the 192.168 subnet, not .169...

Comment: can you connect to `\\192.168.40.40\\` without the `c$` if so it might be an issue with your forest and not your network

Comment: no, when i only enter the IP, I get a window that asks for: username and password, and it also specifies the domain I am on - domain1. How do i change it to domain2 for 192.168.40.40?

Comment: `domain2\user_id` as the user name. Also it would appear this has nothing to do with networking and just inter domain authentication

Comment: when doing: \\192.168.40.40\domain2\user_id, it gives me a windows security window, but the domain on there is domain1, my current domain, and not domain2 - and I cannot change it

Comment: Can you post a screen cap?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to login with a user that does have access. Usually if it doesn't ask for your password you will have to force the correct credentials when connecting and the easiest way is by mapping a drive:

from command line:

```
net use * \\192.168.40.40\C$ /USER:domain2\username
Enter the password for 'domain2\username' to connect to '192.168.40.40': (your password)
```

'username' must be an administrator account on the target PC to access the admin share C$, the command will use the next available drive letter starting with Z:

To do the same thing in the gui, check the box to connect with different credentials, then use the correct domain:

[image: connect1 image]

[image: connect2 image]

If that also fails I would check your firewall/discover-ability settings. Additionally, you could right-click>share a folder normally so you don't have any trouble with the hidden admin shares like `C$`.

I'm not 100% sure it will authenticate correctly to another domain, but I don't have one to test with. A local account should always work though if you have one, just use the target computername as the domain. ex:

```
net use * \\192.168.40.40\C$ /USER:192.168.40.40\Administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use GPO and there is 2 way trust between this 2 domains . You can Use GPP to  add a user  to the local machine Administrator group .

Comment: gpp? How would I do this using windows explorer and the IP eg. \\192.168.40.40 ?

Comment: Just a sample on how to use GPP to add a user to Local Administrator group http://rmlinar.net/blog/2012/06/01/add-specific-domain-account-to-local-administrators-group-using-gpo-sccm-2012/

Answer (score 0):

The most simple may be register your PC in both domains. Be sure your PC have access to both in the local network.

Another one solution may be to do a VPN to the domain 2.